# How to add a foreign key constraint with the annotations

Tags: java, micronaut, micronaut-data

I have a 2 entities `ParentEntity` and `ChildEntity` where the `ChildEntity` references the `ParentEntity`. This is a many (child) to one (parent) relationship and is defined as follows:

```
@MappedEntity
public record ChildEntity (
    @Id Long id,
    String name,
    @Relation(Kind.MANY_TO_ONE) ParentEntity parent)  {
}
```

and

```
@MappedEntity
public record ParentEntity (@Id Long id,  
                            String name) {
}
```

Micronaut Data executes the following SQL queries when creating the schema:

> CREATE TABLE `parent_entity` (`id` BIGINT NOT NULL,`name` VARCHAR(255)
> NOT NULL);

> CREATE TABLE `child_entity` (`id` BIGINT NOT NULL,`name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,`parent_id` BIGINT NOT NULL);

I am expecting (or would like) the foreign key constraint to be added to enforce referential integrity, so that `parent_id` must always be of value `parentEntity.id`

How do I do this on the MappedEntity classes (ChildEntity, ParentEntity etc) while still using Micronaut Data JDBC? (no Hibernate or JPA etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a database migration tool like flyway to create appropriate tables.